# Flutter wrong key error please follow documents on Android devices

Tags: flutter

Flutter error wrong key

Wrong key try to follow documents

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific and clarify your question, please?

Comment: Ok to clarify the question after the splash screen I tap on button add user and the this screen pop (image above)and tell me wrong key try to follow documents 
Is happening just on real devices but on Android studio android emulator